# Комбинация typedef-ов

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
class A{};

template<typename T>
using Specialization_1 = A<T, int>;

template<typename T>
using Specialization_2 = A<T, double>;

template<typename T>
using Specialization_3 = A<int, T>;
```

Можно ли указать такой шаблон, чтобы он обозначал исключительно следующее:

1) `Specialization_1 || Specialization_2`

2) `Specialization_1 || Specialization_3`

3) `Specialization_2 || Specialization_3` ?

Comment: "Можно ли указать такой тип...". Неясно, что вы имеете в виду. Среди вышеприведенного нет пока ни одного *типа*, а есть лишь *шаблоны* типов (шаблоны классов)..

Comment: @AnT исправил вопрос

Comment: Что значит «или» между двумя типами? Я бы на Вашем месте описал реальную задачу, а не этот вопрос, т.к., на мой взгляд, Вы что-то не то пытаетесь делать.

Comment: @ixSci нужен шаблон, который обозначает либо один, либо другой шаблон

Comment: И что это означает? Как будет определяться какой из них нужен?

Comment: @ixSci с помощью шаблонного параметра

Comment: Хорошо, допустим такой метод существует. Напишите в вопросе как Вы собираетесь использовать это. Ещё раз повторяю, ничего пока в Вашем вопросе не ясно и то, что приходится из Вас клещами вытягивать подробности никак не способствует скорейшему решению Вашего вопроса.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, автор хочет увидеть:

```
    template<typename T1, typename T2>
    using Specialization_2_or_3 
    = typename  std::enable_if<   
            std::is_same<T2,double>::value ||  std::is_same<T1,int>::value ,
            A<T1, T2> >::type;

    Specialization_2_or_3<int, int> a1; // ok
    Specialization_2_or_3<double, int> a2; // error
```

?